# Loop For use in setinterval carousel

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem with my setinterval, that is to say that I would like my index to start at -1 as it is when i go to 1 and the index goes to 0 to add d-none but that does not does not give the desired result so if my i === 1 else index ===0 and y cant y have try multiple function but its not good

code html:

```html
<section class="mb-5">
        <div class="carou mb-5 pb-5">
            <div class="divCarou">
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products_mini/product-luxry-sofa.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="divPJS1 pt-3">
                        <p>Luxury Sofa</p>
                        <p class="pRjs">$600.00</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products_mini/product-gloves.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center gap-4 mt-3">
                        <div class="bRoun1">
                            <p>SALE!</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>Luxury Sofa</p>
                            <p class="pRjs">$600.00</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products_mini/product-cups.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="divPJS1 pt-3">
                        <p>Luxury Sofa</p>
                        <p class="pRjs">$600.00</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products_mini/product-bag.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center gap-4 mt-3">
                        <div class="bRoun1">
                            <p>SALE!</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>Luxury Sofa</p>
                            <p class="pRjs">$600.00</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divCarou d-none">
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products_mini/product-bed.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products_mini/product-modern-sofa.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products_mini/product-plates.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products_mini/product-shoes.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divCarou d-none">
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products_mini/product-tshitr.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products/product-bag-2-700x500.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products/product-jacket-700x500.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products_mini/product-plates.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divCarou d-none">
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products/product-tshitr-white-700x500.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products_mini/product-bag.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products_mini/product-cups.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="imgBright">
                        <img class="imgJS2" src="./public/img/products_mini/product-plates.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex gap-3 justify-content-center">
            <i class="fa-regular fa-circle btnCarou active"></i>
            <i class="fa-regular fa-circle btnCarou"></i>
            <i class="fa-regular fa-circle btnCarou"></i>
            <i class="fa-regular fa-circle btnCarou"></i>
        </div>
    </section>
```

code js:

```js
let i2 = document.querySelectorAll(".btnCarou");
let i3 = document.querySelectorAll(".btnCarou");
let divCarou = document.querySelectorAll(".divCarou");
let divCarou2 = document.querySelectorAll(".divCarou");

function Carou2() {
    setInterval( () => {
        for (let i = 1, index = 0 ; i <  i2.length, index = i3.length; i++ , index++) {
            if (![... i2[i].classList].includes("active")) {
                i2[i].classList.add("active");
                divCarou[i].classList.remove("d-none");
                if ([... i3[index].classList].includes("active")) {
                    i3[index].classList.remove("active");
                    divCarou2[index].classList.add("d-none");
                }
            }
        }
    }, 2000)
}

Carou2()
```